# O365 API return all meetings for specific date including recurring meetings

Tags: api, exchangewebservices, office365

Is there an API query that will return all meetings for a specific date including recurring meetings from O365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

../EWS/OData/Me/Events?$top=100&$filter=End ge 2014-06-06T22:30:00Z and Start le 2020-12-14T22:30:00Z

All times are in UTC.

Comment: This query does not seem to be returning recurrences, only events of Type "SingleInstance" and "SeriesMaster" from what I have seen.

Comment: This now seems to be working. Was not working before...Thanks!

Comment: FYI. Now, "Occurences" are not being returned using your query above.

Comment: You mean, they were just an hour ago but are not now?

Comment: Yes, using your query above on all occassions. Am now only getting back SingleInstance and SeriesMaster events

Comment: Can you share the exact query you are using?

Comment: It is working now. This is bizarre. I used your query above `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Events?$top=100&$filter=End ge 2014-06-06T22:30:00Z and Start le 2020-12-14T22:30:00Z` and my own `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Events?$top=100&$filter=Start ge 2014-07-10T05:30:00Z and Start le 2014-07-11T05:00:00Z` for a specific day. Both are working, and also not working a few minutes ago.

Comment: That is strange. Well, let me know if you see some issues around it.

Comment: We are having an issue where "Occurrences" are not being returned for some O365 users. We tested by sending the same recurring meeting to multiple users. The occurrences for this meeting using the query `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Events?$top=100&$filter=Start ge 2014-09-09T05:00:00Z and Start le 2014-09-010T04:59:59Z` were being returned for some, not for others. Any ideas on what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Photohunts, the query filter has to be End ge <x> and Start le <y>.  Start ge <x> and Start le <y> will not work. We know this is not intuitive and we are fixing it.